# JSX transformer for React is not working. Can't find the mistake

Tags: gulp, browserify, babeljs, reactjs

**UPDATE:** I can't believe it. After hours and hours of trying all kinds of gulp magic I don't understand, it was the missing `</script>` closing tag in the index.html for the bundle.js

I'm really stumped on this one. I have started creating a React.js application, and I don't want to use the HTML side jsx transformer but precompile it! Currently I'm doing the following:

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.js">
    </script>
    ....
    <script type="text/babel" src="build/bundle.js"/>
```

This works. But when I use the precompiler via gulp/browserify/reactify/transform, it shows a blank page when I start up the (WebStorm or BrowserSync) server. I'm confused because the "bundle.js" is plain JavaScript - atleast I think it is...? All the jsx syntax has been converted to JavaScript. Here's the gulpfile code:

```
'use strict';

var watchify = require('watchify');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var reactify = require('reactify');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var babel = require('babel');
var libs = ['material-ui', 'react', 'react-tap-event-plugin'];

gulp.task('default', ['vendor', 'bundle', 'browser-sync']);

gulp.task('vendor', function () {
var b = browserify();

libs.forEach(function(lib) {
    b.require(lib);
});
return b.bundle()
    .pipe(source('vendor.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
});

gulp.task('bundle', bundle);
var b = watchify(browserify('./components/app.jsx', watchify.args));
b.on('update', bundle);
b.transform(reactify);
b.on('log', gutil.log);

libs.forEach(function(lib) {
    b.external(lib);
});

function bundle() {
    return b.bundle()
        .on('error', gutil.log.bind(gutil, 'Browserify Error'))
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
};

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init(["build/bundle.js", "css/*.css"],{
        server: {
            baseDir: "./"
        }
    });
});
```

And the bundle.js:

http://pastebin.com/56ep1dT7

The full index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>learn react</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-     core/5.8.23/browser.js"></script>
    <script src="build/vendor.js"></script>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500'    rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mountPoint"/>
    <script type="text/babel" src="build/bundle.js"/>
</body>
```

As you can see I load a vendor.js in the head tag of the index.html, which I guess is browsercompatible JavaScript as well.

Anyway I hope I provided all necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use actual es6 syntax? because that would be the only reason for using babel, but if you are precompiling everything already,(assuming you use es6) transpile es6 with babel es5 beforehand so you only have to load bundle.js in the browser without using any other magic, you are precompiling anyway.

so then u can just get rid of babel browser
 <--- this won't do anything because i don't see any es6 syntax in your code.

```
-  so try using a normal scripttag if you arent using es6
-  if you are using es6 add the babel process to the gulp task
-  remove babel-browser completely ,u don't want to do that within the client on page load anyway,  it will decrease performance (just precompile)
```

u are actually requiring babel to your gulptask already but don't use it:)

Comment: babel seems to be the new and only supported way to transpile jsx in the browser, according to reacts official page. btw i found the error, it was the missing closing script tag. such a beginner mistake.

Comment: Yes im not using the babel tag anymore. im successfully precompiling now. i had a blank page without the closing script tag. As for reactify: why change the order? and which order? reactify before bunding?

Comment: @danillo2k, reactify is being deprecated in favor of babel.

Comment: I still dont understand the problem with the order of reactify and bundling. i am bundling like this: http://pastebin.com/5kXa8kie and it works fine!

Comment: yes i misread, and i didnt look to your pastebin correctly it was already precomiled :) (still early here :P ) u just had to remove the babel script tag as u did, after u fixed your problem , so actually u answered your own question my bad :) but @FakeRainBrigand is right about reactify :) 
-anyways glad that u solved it